# iphone programming, List of cities and countries for searching

Tags: iphone, countries

Hi there
I am wondering if there an inbuilt or available api to gather a list of countries and cities for an iphone app? 
I am looking to add a search bar where the user can type in a part of city name and a selectable list of cities ordered by country is show. Is there any in-built way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not built in. You'll need to find a database of data you need somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hooked up with a third party provider, in this case, customweather.com, who can provide a searchable city and country information. It's a paid solution, i am wondering if there is a free solution..

Thanks